# Possible potential pitfalls when generating licenses from unix timestamps?

Tags: php, authentication, hash

I've built a simple authentication server for an application, currently, it generates licenses based on the purchaser's email-address like so:

licenses.php

```
$uid = hash("sha256", $email);
```

This worked fine, until I saw a customer buying my application twice using the same email address, resulting in a duplicate license.

Are there any potential pitfalls when I change my licensing generation from email to, for example, this?

```
$uid = hash("sha256", time() . $email);
```

Comment: sha256 is a insecure method to encode such a sensible data with. You should have a look at at least md5 + a salt string + time(). Or bcrypt. Also it's a good idea to deactivate a pending license after it has been used.

Comment: deleted comment. no interaction on OP's part.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, I wasn't sure what to do with your comment. Why would it matter if I was using a database or not?

Comment: it could probably facilitate things and using a flag for given rows.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What do you mean by "using a flag for given rows", I'm not very familiar with databases.

Comment: Say for example, if a user already got a license, the SQL would be something like this: `UPDATE table SET paid ='paid' WHERE user='$user' AND license = 'xxx'` - A `SELECT` would be something like `SELECT user FROM table WHERE user='$user' AND datefield = 'YYYY-mm-dd'` as an example. I'm not sure whether you're allowing for dates, but that's the general idea of using a db.